# How can I store unique data with asyncstorage in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

In React Native I want to store object array data with a unique id each time I type in the textbox. I'm using async storage but don't know how to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement something like this

First run

```
npm i @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

And then create a AsyncStore.js or similar file:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export const storeObject = async (object) => {
  const id = await createId()
  const identified = {...object, id }
  const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(identified);
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('@object-' + id, jsonValue);
};

export const getObject = async (id) => {
  const storedObject = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@object-' + id);
  if (storedObject){
    return JSON.parse(storedObject );
  }
};

export const storeIds = async (ids) => {
  const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(ids);
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('@object-ids', jsonValue);
};
export const getIds = async (id, ids) => {
  const storedIds = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@object-ids');
  if (storedIds) {
    return JSON.parse(storedIds );
  }
};

const createId = async() => {
  const ids = await getIds();
  const id = Math.max(ids) + 1
  await storeIds([...ids,id])
  return id;
}
```

Edit: I added some untested unique identifier code

Comment: from where the unique id will generate? I'm just passing a state variable each time I'm taking input from the textinput box then increasing the value of the variable. This is temporarily working but when I'm closing the app and getting text again the variable starts again from the beginning that overwrites the previous value with that id.

Comment: I think that's a flaw in your handling logic, not the storage. Sounds like you should generate id yourself, e.g.
1. fetch all from storage
2. create new item, and add a new item with id = max(storedObjects.id)+1
3. store new item